# Parallel Binary Search

Tags: parallel-processing, binary-search

I'm just starting to learn about parallel programming, and I'm looking at binary search.

This can't really be optimized by throwing more processors at it right? I know it's supposedly dividing and conquering, but you're really "decreasing and conquering" (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm#Parallelism)).

Or could you possibly parallelize the comparisons? (if `X` is less than `array[mid]`, search from `low` to `mid - 1`; else if `X` is greater than `array[mid]` search from `mid + 1` to `high`, else return `mid`, the index of `X`)

Or how about you give half of the array to one processor to do binary search on, and the other half to another? Wouldn't that be wasteful though? Because it's decreasing and conquering rather than simply dividing and conquering? Thoughts?

Answer (score 17):

You can easily use parallelism.

For `k` is less than `n` processors, split the array into `n/k` groups and assign a processor to each group.

Run binary search on that group.

Now the time is **log(n/k)**.

There is also a crew method that is **logn/log(k+1)**.

Comment: Can you link to the crew method?

Comment: Please think it through. What would happen on the first iteration on the buckets where the key is NOT present.

Comment: Here is a good paper with the crew algorithm: 
https://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/TOPICS/ramsey/parasearch.pdf

Comment: If you have a processor for each cell, I think it will take an 0(1) to do a search.

Comment: And how long would it take to set up all those cells?  O(n).  You could create two subsections, and run a binary search in parallel on each half of your data, but the amount of work created in setting up those separate threads is going to be SIGNIFICANTLY more work than the amount of work you saved.  Big O doesn't care, but real life certainly does.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have much experience in parallel programming, but I doubt this is a good candidate for parallel processing. Each step of the algorithm depends on performing one comparison, and then proceeding down a set "path" based on this comparison (you either found your value, or now have to keep searching in a set "direction" based on the comparison). Two separate threads performing the same comparison won't get you anywhere any faster, and separate threads will both need to rely on the same comparison to decide what to do next, so they can't really do any useful, divided work on their own.

As far as your idea of splitting the array, I think you are just negating the benefit of binary search in this case. Your value (assuming it's in your array), will either be in the top or the bottom half of your array. The first comparison (at the midpoint) in a binary search is going to tell you which half you should be looking in. If you take that even further, consider breaking an array of N elements into N different binary searches (a naive attempt to parallel-ize). You are now doing N comparisons, when you don't need to. You are losing the power of binary search, in that each comparison will narrow down your search to the appropriate subset.

Hope that helps. Comments welcome.

Answer (score 4):

I would think it certainly qualifies for parallelisation.  At least, across two threads.  Have one thread do a depth-first search, and the other do a breadth-first search.  The winner is the algorithm that performs the fastest, which may be different from data-set to data-set.

Comment: In case any reader thinks I'm being flippant, I'm actually not.  For time-critical sections where an algorithm might not itself parallelise, using multiple algorithms with different performance characteristics may be a valid optimisation to keep the worst-case big-Oh in line.

Comment: How can you apply DFS or BFS to binary search?

Comment: @Ari I guess you would structure the array as binary search tree

Answer (score 3):

Parallel implementation can speed up a binary search, but the improvement is not particularly significant.  Worst case, the time required for a binary search is `log_2(n)` where `n` is the number of elements in the list.  A simple parallel implementation breaks the master list into `k` sub-lists to be bin-searched by parallel threads.  The resulting worst-case time for the binary search is `log_2(n/k)` realizing a theoretical decrease in the search time.

**Example:**
A list of `1024` entries takes as many as `10` cycles to binary search using a single thread.  Using `4` threads, each thread only would only take `8` cycles to complete the search.  And using `8` threads, each thread takes `7` cycles.  Thus, an `8` threaded parallel binary search could be up to `30%` faster than the single threaded model.

However, his speed-up should not be confused with a improvement in efficiency:  The `8` threaded model actually executes `8 * 7 = 56` comparisons to complete the search compared to the `10` comparisons executed by the single threaded binary search.  It is up to the discretion of the programmer if the marginal gain in speed of a parallel application of binary search is appropriate or advantageous for their application.

Comment: I should add that this is an example of 'decrease-and-conquer' as opposed to the generally more desirable 'divide-and-conquer' for a parallel implementation.  In this case, each thread performs a smaller problem than the original search and is therefore faster, but the sum of those problems is greater than the original problem.  If we could manage a 'divide-and-conquer' implementation here, the sum of the smaller problems would be the same as the original single-threaded implementation, except k times faster (where k is the number of parallel threads).

Comment: 30% speed up is significant!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in the classical sense of parallelization (multi-core), binary search and BST are not much better.

There are techniques like having multiple copies of the BST on L1 cache for each processor. Only one processor is active but the gains from having multiple L1 caches can be great (4 cycles for L1 vs 14 cycles for L2).

In real world problems you are often searching multiple keys at the same time.

Now, there is another kind of parallelization that can help: SIMD! Check out "Fast architecture sensitive tree search on modern CPUs and GPUs" by a team from Intel/UCSC/Oracle (SIGMOD 2010). It's very cool. BTW I'm basing my current research project on this very paper.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure binary search can be speed up by a factor of log (M) where M is the number of processors. log(n/M) = log(n) - log(M) > log(n)/ log(M) for a constant M. I do not have a proof for a tight lower bound, but if M=n, the execution time is O(1), which cannot be any better. An algorithm sketch follows.

**Parallel_Binary_Search(sorted_arraylist)**

1. Divide your sorted_arraylist into M chunks of size n/M.
2. Apply one step of comparison to the middle element of each chunk.
3. If a comparator signals equality, return the address and terminate.
4. Otherwise, identify both adjacent chunks where comparators signaled (>) and (<), respectively.
5. Form a new Chunk starting from the element following the one that signaled (>) and ending at the element preceding the one that signaled (<).
6. If they are the same element, return fail and terminate.
7. Otherwise, Parallel_Binary_Search(Chunk)