# How do I convert this sequential iterative binary search to a parallel algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, sequential

I have this array (A) with n elements that are guaranteed to be sorted and I need to perform a binary search on them in a parallel system. I started off by making this binary search algorithm. It's iterative because I'm not sure how to incorporate recursion into parallel processing, just yet.

```
/* Looking for element k in array A of length n */
min = 0;
max = n - 1;
while(min <= max)
{
    midpoint = min + ((max-min)/2); //index
    if(A[midpoint] > k) //discard upper half
        max = midpoint - 1;
    else if(A[midpoint] < k) //discard lower half
        min = midpoint + 1;
    else
        return midpoint; //Found k, return index
}
return -1; //not found
```

In the parallel algorithm, I've got access to p processors and it is a system that allows concurrent reads, but exclusive writes. The real problem is that I'm still thinking sequentially. That is, I can't seem to see any way that this could be done with more than one processor as you can't "throw away" the unneeded part of the array without first knowing where you are in terms of the midpoint value. It seems so inherently sequential.

Pseudo Code:

```
Global:  //Variables accessible by all processors
  index; //index of k
  p;     //number of processors
  i;     //the i^th processor
  n;     //number elements in array A
  A[0, 1, ... , (n-1)];
local:   //Variables accessible by only the owning processor
         //Not sure what I need yet
Begin
  Spawn(P1, P2 . . . P(p-1)); //"create" the p processors
  for all P where 0 <= i <= (p-1) do //each processor does the following code
    //I'm stuck here
  endfor
End
```

One last thing: I saw a question posted by a user asking if there was a way to do a binary search with parallel processing. There was no really decisive answer to that question because the two relevant answers both received 1 vote. One said it was effectively impossible because it is a step by step process while the other seem pretty confident that it would be really easy to implement. What are your thoughts?

[Previous Parallel Binary Search Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423873/parallel-binary-search-would-be-silly-right)

Comment: I was gonna suggest split and run.. before I noticed that it was the second answer in the one you linked. It is technically inefficient, but probably faster. But I guess the reason for the confusion in the other question is because this isnt parellelizing binary search, its just parellelizing search itself.

Comment: Splitting into `P` chunks reduces the time for the search phase by `O(log P)` steps. But setting up `P` threads takes `O(P)` time.

Answer (score 3):

Whilst it is technically possible to make binary search run in parallel, I wouldn't advise it.

The best algorithms for running in parallel are those which have discrete elements separate to each other that can run simultaneously. For instance rendering 3d graphics into a video is good because each frame is independent and can be given to a separate processor.

You could divide the tree up into segments so that each processor would have something to work on, but considering the nature of the binary search only one of the many processors would find the answer hence wasting the computing effort of all the others that didn't have the search element in their segment. This doesn't even account for the overhead for threading.

Now if on the other hand you had a series of searches to do on a single binary tree that would be a different matter. You could have a job queue that all your threads feed from, perform the binary search and respond to. This way you could run many searches in parallel rather than parts of a search. If you were looking to optimise it further you could also implement a cache.

In short, don't try to split up an individual binary search across processors as you won't gain anything but wasted processor time. But if you are doing many searches you can gain by running the many searches in parallel.

Answer (score 3):

As with all problems to solve in parallel…this depends a lot on the size of your data, the speed of your messages / shared memory, and your requirements.

How fast are write locks, and how fast is synchronization? If they’re fast enough (e.g., using shared memory on a single machine) and your data size is big enough, a specific kind of “split and run” technique could work. You could think of it as follows:

Binary search is a divide-and-conquer approach, where you update the range you’re examining after each iteration — the range is halved at each iteration. Instead of dividing the current range into 2, you could divide it into `p` pieces, where each process is responsible for one of the pieces; at each iteration, the “winning” piece (the one that has the target value in its range) writes the new range to be searched to memory, and you synchronize the processes before starting the next iteration. If you have enough data, going from halving your data to reducing your data by `p` each time could be a win. You’d go from $O(log_2(x))$ to $O(log_p(x))$.

This sort of approach only works if writing and synchronization are sufficiently fast, since it depends on doing a *lot* of writing and synchronization. If you’re doing this across a cluster, these become expensive. If communication between processes is difficult, perhaps the best you can do is the “split and run” suggested in the other post you linked to. Specifically, take each `p`th element of your sorted list, and put it on a different node. Then, when a request comes in, do binary searches on all of the nodes. If the values in your array are unique, only one of the nodes will find the answer, and that node can return the result. It’s a relatively poor parallelism, because you’re repeating a lot of the work — you’re ignoring the order that exists *between* the arrays on the different nodes. But it will give you a speed-up from $O(log_2(x))$ to $O(log_2(x/p))$.

In practice, it can be hard to know what approach will work well on your hardware ahead of time. Often, you have to strike an empirical balance between making sure all processes are active all the time, and making sure you don’t lose too much time to communication overhead.